# Delphi Firemonkey get UTC time

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

How does one get the UTC time in Firemonkey?

I tried this code from another Stackoverflow answer but it appears GetSystemTime() is not available in FMX.

```
function NowUTC: TDateTime;
Var UTC: TSystemTime;
begin
  GetSystemTime(UTC);
  Result := SystemTimeToDateTime(UTC);
end;
```

Comment: [`GetSystemTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtime) is a function in the Microsoft Windows operating system. So if your app only needs to run on Windows, you can use it -- even in a FXM app. But if you need the app to run on other operating systems (or "other 'operating systems'" as I usually say), it is indeed not available. In the first case, just add `Winapi.Windows` to the `uses` clause.

Comment: This is definitely a Firemonkey app, headed to those "other operating systems."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add `DateUtils` to the `uses` clause, you can use the [`TTimeZone`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.TTimeZone) class, its [`Local`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.TTimeZone.Local) class property, and the [`ToUniversalTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.TTimeZone.ToUniversalTime) method:

```
ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now)));
```

Answer (score 0):

TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now) doesn't work during DST change on 30. October 3:00 >> 2:00. Beacause during changing, there is 2:00-3:00 time twice and to get correct UTC, You have to set ForceDaylight in function ToUniversalTime to true/false during transient time.

There is a TDateTime helper in DateUtils unit, which reflects this DST transient time on a UNIX (Android) system too and return the correct UTC time. On Unix are used functions gettimeofday and gmtime_r.

```
result:=TDateTime.NowUTC;
```